# WebReference and Source Control

Tags: c#, web-services, version-control

I have a C# application that uses several web services which were added to my project as web references.  I want to know what files i should check into source control.

in my project there is a folder structure from my project directory that looks like this:

```
Project
    Web References
        WS
            WS.wsdl
            Reference.cs
            Reference.map
            ...misc .datasource and .xsd files
```

Which of these files should i put in source control?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest keeping *all* those files under source control, but only for completeness for other developers using your project's source code, or having to perform a Checkout/Get Latest on any new machine (after your dev machine's hard drive dies, etc.).

Once Visual Studio builds the web reference, all those files are built and remain unchanged until you 'Refresh Web Reference'. If you modify them yourself, i.e. change a datatype, or remove an XML attribute (I've had to do that for some obscure runtime SOAP problem), then check those changes in as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your nant script or visual studio solution or what have you rebuilds any particular files on each build, then don't check those in, as it'll just lead to confusion. Otherwise check it all in.